# How to solve the equal height column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make equal three column.I'm using bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
            <div class="in">
                    <div class="icon-introduction"></div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

                    </p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 nopadding hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <div class="image">
              <div id="image-introduction">
              <img src="images/sms.png" id="sms-icon">
                    <img src="images/men.png">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
            <div class="in">
                <div class="icon-introduction blue"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                     when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
                     It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
                     remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
                     and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I saw another pages but I can't solve this problem.
I'm using display:table but it does not change.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1s4ut87L/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this, http://jsfiddle.net/1s4ut87L/1/

You have defined min-height for `.in`, change it to `height` property

```
.in{
    width: 100%;
    height: 197px;
    background: #ddd;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

and set `overflow:auto;`

**Edit:**

According to the comment by OP, the all columns should take the height equal to the largest div.

So I changed my fiddle a little,
see this  http://jsfiddle.net/1s4ut87L/7/

And this is the whole css,

```
.row{
   display:table;
}
.nopadding{
     display:table-cell;
    background: #ddd;   
}

.image{
    background: #FFF;   
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: @sankhas.. let me know if this doesn't help you

Comment: I don't want to use oveflow.

Comment: so where you want to put the overflown content, or do you want all the divs with maximum size any element occupies?

Comment: I want all the same size of a div larger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It's not the perfect choice but it will work.

```
.row {
    display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```